# How to store CoreData to iCloud account iOS Programming?

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud

I have stored data in core-data into my project. I want to take backup of my App to iCloud. So when user changes mobile, he could recover all the data.

Is there any good tutorial or helping documentation regarding this.

I want to know

**1. Can I save my data on iCloud?**

**2. Can I save whole db as a single file?**

**3. Can I extract/download iCloud back in similar format/structure?**

Thanks.

Comment: Is not it default behavior ? it is backed up automatically

Comment: I have no idea about it. Can you guide. How it saves?

Comment: when user backs up the data to the iCloud , CoreData database is already included in this backup and it will be automatically restored later,

Comment: So, you want to say that my app must open iCloud, and it will automatically backup all DB in same structure. and When user signs in from another device, it will automatically backup it. am I right?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes
2. No
3. Yes

Greetings Program!

I have integrated iCloud and Core Data in my app using a modified version of this class:

https://gist.github.com/mluisbrown/7015953

In my app I have a setting which I use to set the NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey in the persistentStoreCoordinator option property (nil = non-iCloud enabled).

When using iCloud, it uses the same structure as the data model used for Core Data but iCloud data is not sync'd/saved/backed up to Core Data. I use the persistentStoreCoordinator.migratePersistentStore method to copy the data from iCloud to Core Data but you have to check for duplicates yourself.

Wg